# Как сделать слайдер с grid

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, scss, vue3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой слайдер? Вся проблема в том что из бэкенда приходит лист в котором есть заголовок и контент, если нет контента то блок должен быть маленьким и без фона. И задний фон должен быть рандомным

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Можете привести пример листа который приходит с сервера? Вам всегда приходят такие листы (Два без контента, три с контентом)? `И задний фон должен быть рандомным` - какие цвета должны попадаться?

Comment: data: [
        {
          title: "ОБРАТНАЯ СВЯЗЬ",
          content: "по вопросам высшего и послевузовского образования"
        },
        {
          title: "ДИСТАНЦИОННОЕ ОБУЧЕНИЕ В УНИВЕРСИТЕТЕ",
          content: ""
        },
        {
          title: "ВАКАНСИИ В УНИВЕРСИТЕТЕ",
          content: ""
        },
        {
          title: "ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЕ ПОРТАЛЫ",
          content: "направленые на расширение области применения англиского языка"
        }
]